# check if field is empty and populate it with another field in django

Tags: python, django, model

Recently i built a super tiny inventory system. it generates barcode from the item id. so now now I want to add the functionality of using an already generated code to search for item.

```
So i have the fields like this previously 
class Inv(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField()  
    model_number = models.CharField()  
    manufacturer = models.CharField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.id
```

Now

```
class Inv(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField()  
    model_number = models.CharField()  
    manufacturer = models.CharField()
    barcode = models.CharField(blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.id
```

what I want to achieve is in a situation where an item doesn't have a barcode image and I  want to save the item and add the id into the barcode field how do I do that efficiently? 
this is the save method I have written

```
def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, *args,**kwargs):
    # if self.barcode == None:
    #     self.barcode = self.id
    #     self.save()
super(Inv, self).save(force_insert, force_update, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Your code is right!, just recommend to use `self.barcode is None:` instead of equal symbol. There's no need to self.save since you're calling super.save after that.

Comment: I was thinking maybe I should add convert Id to sting before saving it?

Comment: I think it's better for you to check and see if Django casts your id before saving or not. If it saves, it means it was converted to str. If not, you'll get an error.